# Cannot start service postgres: OCI runtime creStarting localterra_terrad_1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, terra

I'm using docker-compose for terramoney.

Here is ***docker-compose.yml*** file.

```
version: "3"

services:
  terrad:
    image: terramoney/localterra-core:0.5.18
    volumes:
      - ./config:/root/.terra/config
    networks:
      - terra
    ports:
      - "26657:26657"
      - "1317:1317"
      - "9090:9090"
      - "9091:9091"
    command: terrad start
  oracle:
    image: terramoney/pseudo-feeder:0.5.6
    depends_on:
      - terrad
    volumes:
      - ./config/config.toml:/app/config.toml
    networks:
      - terra
    environment:
      TESTNET_LCD_URL: http://terrad:1317
    command: start
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - terra
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dev
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dev
  # redis:
  #   image: redis:latest
  #   networks:
  #     - terra
  #   ports:
  #     - "6379:6379"
  fcd-collector:
    image: terramoney/fcd:1.0.14
    depends_on:
      - terrad
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/app/logs
    networks:
      - terra
    env_file: fcd.env
    command: collector
    restart: unless-stopped
  fcd-api:
    image: terramoney/fcd:1.0.14
    depends_on:
      - terrad
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/app/logs
    networks:
      - terra
    ports:
      - 3060:3060
    env_file: fcd.env
    command: start

networks:
  terra:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run `sudo docker-compose up`, I got this error.

> Starting localterra_terrad_1 ...  Starting localterra_postgres_1 ...
> error
>
> ERROR: for localterra_postgres_1  Cannot start service postgres: OCI
> runtime creStarting localterra_terrad_1   ... error
> 2d5e1c2ce6c114821010c6: unknown
>
> ERROR: for localterra_terrad_1  Cannot start service terrad: OCI
> runtime create failed: container with id exists:
> 0d03712d982f9b6f1d67c36735f4aefddb874e65958965e1bca54a782f525c6e:
> unknown
>
> ERROR: for postgres  Cannot start service postgres: OCI runtime create
> failed: container with id exists:
> ea889e63356e0d77d5196b2c73d1696089944fcbab2d5e1c2ce6c114821010c6:
> unknown
>
> ERROR: for terrad  Cannot start service terrad: OCI runtime create
> failed: container with id exists:
> 0d03712d982f9b6f1d67c36735f4aefddb874e65958965e1bca54a782f525c6e:
> unknown ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

If anyone familiar with docker and terramoney, please help me.

I may have installed docker incorrectly.

After install docker, my docker desktop is stopped.

This is root directory

```
├─── config/
├─── img/
├─── pseudo-feeder/
└─── terracore/
     docker-compose.yml
     fcd.env
     init.sql
     LICENSE
     README.md
```

Comment: Did you see the error msg, Container with Id exists? Have you tried to docker-compose rm before?

Comment: I ran into this problem today and I'm not exactly sure what caused the problem, but when I did a `docker image ls`, I saw a lot of postgres images listed.  I did a `docker image rm <image_id>` for each postgres image and was able to build without the error.